# Is there a list, database or API that contains the all the product information in India

Tags: data-request, api, products, barcodes, india

I'm looking for a database for accessing the product information which are available in India. The list of UPC's and ISBN's or all the information of a product.

Comment: I have been using this API for serval time because I work for the world e-commerce finance analysis. So I need a API to help me to get the information about the products information in world wild. I'm also interested about your question. Could u show some Inda products around u to do a test? Thx for your work :).@Jan Doggen

Answer (score 3):

For the ISBN's, you may find interest in [Worldcat](http://www.worldcat.org/advancedsearch). It allows searching with ISBN codes, and by language. Hindi is one of the searchable languages. They also offer an API, but to perform unrestricted search requests you have to be affiliated to a Library, otherwise it's free. The other alternative is also to write your own API that scraps the results off web pages.

As for the UPC codes, there is the [UPC database](http://www.upcdatabase.com/) that has millions of items (though, not sure how many Indian UPC codes there are). Otherwise you can also use the [Google Search API for Shopping](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-overview?hl=fr-FR), which is deprecated, but offered until September 2013. To search by UPC codes, you have to use the `gtin` parameter in the URL.

If you are interested, read [this article about the GTIN - Global Trade Item Number](http://www.gtin.info/), which explains how it is related to UPC. If you are not, I'll make it short, the GTIN-12 format is UPC.

Comment: Thanks Jalayn, I will look into GTIN article, I know about the UPC database and EAN database and i also have 1 million products Information but i cant guarantee that the product is available in india. For ISBN i looked into the http://openlibrary.org/ i got the Isbn but the problem is same. This weekend I will look into the worldcat

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Flipkart Affiliate, you can access their Product (and Offers) feed. The products have a custom Flipkart Id and not something general that you can compare with elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Amazon's affiliate program. Their API includes products (lookup by UPC or EAN) from various countries throughout the world. https://affiliate-program.amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

I think u could use some api to help you in your project.

UPC and ISBN, We can call them Gtin code.
It could be 8, 12, 13 or 14 digits long.

You could use this database:
https://market.mashape.com/mignify/gtin2product

It's an easy use API, U can use it to get directly the product information by gtin. Also It could help u to extract the information of a page from E-commerce site. It allows you to search by EAN, UPC or ISBN, even with language variations.

Hope it could help U.

Comment: Are you associated with this product? Then please say so. It says: *world coverage*, does it contain enough data for India to statisfy the question?